# Stop MySQL tolerating multiple NULLs in a UNIQUE constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

My SQL schema is

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
 `bar` INT NULL ,
 `name` VARCHAR (59) NOT NULL ,
 UNIQUE ( `name`, `bar` )
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

MySQL is allowing the following statement to be repeated, resulting in duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO Foo (`bar`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'abc');
```

despite having

```
UNIQUE ( `name`, `bar` )
```

Why is this tolerated and how do I stop it?

Comment: Make it a primary key, which doesn't allow nulls in either field. Or make the fields not null. As per the mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html "For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple null values for columns that can contain null".

Comment: `NULL` is not a value.  As @MarcB says, you need to disallow `NULL` for this

Comment: Looks like it's a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173. (At least some people in the bug report think so)

Comment: @JNK: The last post in the bug report has a point IMHO which says it's a bug. But whatever.

Comment: @juergend - good point, sorry for the overreaction :)  Deleted

Comment: @juergend IMO it's still not a bug, b/c this is too close to counting `NULL` as a value, which it isn't.

Comment: @spraff: You have to understand that `(NULL, 'abc')` is not a duplicate of `(NULL, 'abc')`. They are not equal.

Comment: there are not equal :D ehm, they are.

Comment: @Sebi2020 NULL!=NULL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Warning: This answer is outdated. As of MySQL 5.1, BDB is not supported.**

It depends on `MySQL Engine Type`. `BDB` doesn't allow multiple `NULL` values using `UNIQUE` but `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` allows multiple `NULL`s even with `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, depending on the storage engine, `NULL` may or may not be seen as a unique value. You must be using a storage engine which doesn't recognise `NULL` as a unique value, eg. InnoDB or MyISAM.

To get around this you can create a "null value", such as 99999999, which you can recognise as `NULL` as there is no way to change how your storage engine decides to deal with nulls in unique keys.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a magic number solution.  The real answer is to understand `NULL` and use it appropriately.

Comment: I will not give -1 because the OP seems to think that `NULL` is indeed some magic value. Nor +1 because ill-understanding of concepts should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: You should use the idea suggested by @greenoldman in the comment below instead. Create a boolean field with triggers to set the value based on whether your nullable field is NULL or not and then combine the boolean field in a unique constraint with the other fields that define uniqueness.

---

I found a way around this problem if you must enforce the unique constraint but also need to have a foreign key on the column, thus requiring it to be nullable. My solution was derived from [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173#c421874) and will require a little extra space. This is an example with a numeric id field.

The basic concept is that you have to create another non-nullable field that will have the value of your nullable field with the foreign key duplicated into it with a trigger. The unique constraint will then be enforced on the non-nullable duplicate field. To do this you need to define a non-nullable field with a default value of `0` similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD  `uniq_foo` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

Then you just have to define some triggers like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `my_table_before_insert`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `my_table_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.uniq_foo = IFNULL(NEW.foo_id, 0);
END;;
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `my_table_before_update`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `my_table_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.uniq_foo = IFNULL(NEW.foo_id, 0);
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The concept is great, but execution is too fragile to use. However there is a remedy -- this extra column should be `TINYINT(1)` (meaning -- bool) holding `0` for null and `1` for not-null (or vice-versa, it does not matter) for nullable field. The unique index should use this extra column **additionally** not instead. And that's it -- there is no chance you will get conflict because of magic values, because there is none.

Comment: @greenoldman Great idea! FWIW, I haven't had any trouble using this technique in production with very large and active datasets but I still like your idea better.

Answer (score 0):

BDB doesn't allow multiple NULL values using UNIQUE.
But MySQL drop the BDB engine (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-12.html).

So now : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

> For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.
>   If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.