# Preferred way to create composite unique index with NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have the following values in my database:

[image]

I would like to create a unique key on `tv_series_id+name+tv_season_number+tv_episode_number`. However, the above does not work for my purposes using the conventional:

```
ALTER TABLE main_itemmaster ADD UNIQUE KEY (tv_series_id, tv_season_number, tv_episode_number, name)
```

Because of the null values. What would be a way to solve this at the database level (and not the query side) ?

And to clarify, the above should not be allowed, as "97736-Season 4-4-NULL" is repeated 10 times. The solution I was thinking of implementing as a last resort would be to store an additional string column for uniqueness, so "97736-Season 4-4-" for the above.

Comment: I'm confused.  MySQL allows multiple occurrences of `NULL` values in a unique index (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).  So, your method should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff does the updated last sentence help to clarify?

Comment: Do you have to allow nulls? Couldn't you set a default value for tv_episode_number (e.g. 0)?

Comment: An `ON INSERT` trigger that creates a synthetic key, which you can then include in your composite key.

Comment: @evsheino Yes, there will be nulls, for example, a TV Season or Movie does not have an episode number. Storing it as 0 might work to solve this problem but would screw up a lot of other things.

Comment: @bishop could you please show how I'd create a trigger on those four fields? I'll then accept that answer provided it works.

Comment: @David542 I think this is the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27053371/4321262

Comment: if possible i would avoid any column nullable to be in the composite index. If it really has to be empty string just inject `''` to the column. Indeed I do feel this is a strange design of mysql. Where a column NULL found in a composite index, it can be treated same `NULL` and avoid repetitive records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, my suggestion (untested):

```
ALTER TABLE main_itemmaster ADD COLUMN uniquer BIGINT NOT NULL;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER add_uniquer BEFORE INSERT ON main_itemmaster
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET NEW.uniquer = (SELECT UUID_SHORT());
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
ALTER TABLE main_itemmaster ADD UNIQUE KEY (tv_series_id, tv_season_number, tv_episode_number, name, uniquer);
```

The algorithm behind the uniquer is entirely up to you. I chose a [short UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) here. You might want a long UUID. Or UUID [might not be right for you](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/do-you-really-need-a-uuid-guid). Time-based might work. You could base it on the MD5 of the values in the inserted row.

Comment: How does this enforce uniqueness more than the original constraint? (97736, 4, NULL, 'Season 4', generated_id1) and (97736, 4, NULL, 'Season 4', generated_id2) are both unique.

Comment: Won't this solution prevent any utility of `UNIQUE`?  That is, won't it allow '97736-Season 4-4-foo' to show up twice because of extra "uniquer" column?

Comment: @RickJames Possibly. The OP excludes semantic information about the other data fields, and that other information might practically disqualify a query with those results. While my answer strictly responds to the question, I wonder whether a different approach with a different natural key would make more sense. IOW, I gave a tactical answer to what is possibly a strategic problem.

Answer (score 1):

More simple solution (if you have a lot of fields, which could be NULL and if you still want to have rows unique)

1) add unique_hash field

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME_HERE` 
   ADD `unique_hash` BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'JIRA-ISSUE-ID' AFTER `SOME_EXISTING_FIELD`
   ;
```

2) fill them

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME_HERE SET unique_hash=cast(conv(substring(md5(
    CONCAT(
        IF(field1_id IS NULL, 'NULL',field1_id),'_',
        IF(field2_id IS NULL, 'NULL',field2_id),'_',
        IF(field3_id IS NULL, 'NULL',field3_id),'_',
        IF(field4_id IS NULL, 'NULL',field4_id),'_',
        IF(field5_id IS NULL, 'NULL',field5_id),'_'
    )
), 1, 16), 16, 10) as unsigned integer);
```

3) add unique index on bigint (it would be faster, as complex unique index - because it will be smaller)

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE` ADD UNIQUE (`unique_hash`);
```

4) add trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER add_unique_hash BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_NAME_HERE
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET NEW.unique_hash = (cast(conv(substring(md5(
                               CONCAT(
                                   IF(NEW.field1_id IS NULL, 'NULL',NEW.field1_id),'_',
                                   IF(NEW.field2_id IS NULL, 'NULL',NEW.field2_id),'_',
                                   IF(NEW.field3_id IS NULL, 'NULL',NEW.field3_id),'_',
                                   IF(NEW.field4_id IS NULL, 'NULL',NEW.field4_id),'_',
                                   IF(NEW.field5_id IS NULL, 'NULL',NEW.field5_id),'_'
                               )
                           ), 1, 16), 16, 10) as unsigned integer));
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

5) ENJOY! :)

You will have **realy** unique index on field1_id, field2_id, field3_id, field4_id, field5_id . And NULL values would be allowed only once. No changes on scripts required.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053371/4321262

```
ALTER TABLE main_itemmaster ADD uniq int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

ALTER TABLE main_itemmaster ADD UNIQUE KEY (tv_series_id, tv_season_number, name, uniq);

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER main_itemmaster_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON main_itemmaster
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.uniq = IFNULL(NEW.tv_episode_number, 0);
END;;

CREATE TRIGGER main_itemmaster_before_update BEFORE UPDATE ON main_itemmaster
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.uniq = IFNULL(NEW.tv_episode_number, 0);
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

This will create a new column that will store the tv_episode_number, or 0 if the tv_episode_number is NULL. It is then used in the unique index with tv_series_id, tv_season_number, and name.

The triggers will set the value of the new column and prevent multiple identical rows containing nulls from being inserted or becoming identical after an update.

Now the following insert statement will throw a duplicate entry error if run multiple times:

```
INSERT INTO main_itemmaster (tv_series_id, name, tv_season_number, tv_episode_number) values (97736, 'Season 4', 4, NULL);
```